# How to force PHP to read newlines and returns as <br>

Tags: php, mysql, formatting, plaintext

The title is a little off im sorry. however what the scenario IS.

I'm reading from a MySQL Database the field format is "mediumtext".

At current it knows when there is a new line from hitting enter/return. there is no html involved.

however when i pull this from the database onto my page, there is no formatting. however if you look at the html the code it beautifuly formatted with new lines!

ive already got a find/replace function setup for some simple BBCode so might be able to use this.

so does anybody have ideas on how I can either use my find/replace to find "new lines?" or how to simply force the new lines some how, if you understand me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

- [`nl2br` — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Example from Manual:

```
echo nl2br("Welcome\r\nThis is my HTML document", false);
```

will output

```
Welcome<br>
This is my HTML document
```

Comment: thanks i'll have a look at this, however in the database there doesnt seem to be any \n or \r so will it still work...

Comment: well, you won't see the returns as "\n", but they should be there, as you say you can see the 'breaks' in the code. So if you see newlines/breaks/returns in your database, the "\n" 's are there :)

Comment: ah okay, thank you very much it did in fact work a like a ddream! thanks :D